# Video streaming from xml file(android)

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, listview, android-videoview

I'm creating an android application that can play the video from xml file in `ListView`. But somehow when I clicked on the `ListView`, the error message come out and the application is forcing to stop.

**The listview code is**

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {    
static final String URL = "...";

static final String KEY_LINK = "link";


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
 int position, long id) {

String  myUrl = channelList.get(position).get("url");
Intent n = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this , VideoViewActivity.class);
      n.putExtra("url", myUrl);
      startActivity(n);
```

**VideoView code:**

```
public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity {

Intent n = getIntent();

String myurl = n.getStringExtra("url");
VideoView videoView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);
   
 videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
 MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
 videoView.setMediaController(mc);

 Uri video = Uri.parse(myurl);
 videoView.setVideoURI(video);

 videoView.requestFocus();
 videoView.start();
 }

 }
```

I tried to change the `static final String KEY_LINK = "link";` to `static final String KEY_LINK = "videolocation";` as suggested on other post but it still doesn't work.

#### The crash log are:

```
 E/Trace(29679): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.androidhive/com.example.androidhive.VideoViewActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at : E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at  android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at com.example.androidhive.CustomizedListView$1.onItemClick(CustomizedListView.java:85)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1102)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2945)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3629)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29679):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please add the crash logs

Comment: @JosephusVillarey There's no crash logs.

Comment: @kira4657 `I clicked on the listview, the error message come out and the apps is forcing to stop` and there are no crash logs ??

Comment: then you have a deeper problem. sorry, can't help you. meanwhile, this: http://www.xda-developers.com/android/learn-to-use-a-logcat-to-diagnose-and-fix-your-issues/

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille "Unfortunately, the app has stopped"

Comment: @JosephusVillarey "Unfortunately, the app has stopped"

Comment: @kira4657  open log cat and i am sure you will see the errors there. You just have to copy and paste it here, without looking at the log, we cant just guess what the problem could be :)..

Comment: please read the link from my comment above. that teaches how to get the logs.

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille I edited the post with crash log, thank you.

Comment: i think you have not declared VideoViewActivity  in your manifest.

Comment: @kira4657 wqrahd is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not declared `VideoViewActivity` activity in your manifest. please declare it in manifest and then try.

the logcat shows

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.androidhive/com.example.androidhive.VideoViewActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

in manifest file under application tag write

```
 <activity android:name=".VideoViewActivity ">
 </activity>
```

move this after `setContentView` in video view activity

```
Intent n = getIntent();
String myurl = n.getStringExtra("url");
```

Comment: After I declared in the manifest, this error come out :  E/Trace(31879): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
E/AndroidRuntime(31879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(31879): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidhive/com.example.androidhive.VideoViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: move the intent code in oncreate nethod. i mean to say this part Intent n = getIntent();

String myurl = n.getStringExtra("url");

Comment: because when activity start then you have to get data from intent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem because you haven't register your **VideoViewActivity** in your manifest file. So register under application tag it by

```
<activity android:name=".VideoViewActivity ">
</activity>
```

you should move this

```
 Intent n = getIntent();

 String myurl = n.getStringExtra("url");
```

after onCreate() method. SO it will be

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);


  Intent n = getIntent();
  String myurl = n.getStringExtra("url");
  videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
  MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
  videoView.setMediaController(mc);

  Uri video = Uri.parse(myurl);
  videoView.setVideoURI(video);

  videoView.requestFocus();
  videoView.start();
  }
```